# Как создаются сохранения компьютерных игр

Tags: разработка-игр, хранение-данных

У меня есть несколько вариантов:

- Сохранение состояния оперативной памяти

  - + Плюс в том что подходит для любой игры
  - - Для серьезной игры этот вариант сразу отпадает: файл будет весить 
    порядком 500 мб причем могут загрузится нежелательные параметры как
    громкость музыки например.
- Сохранение всех нужных переменных игры в формате json

  - + Файл будет весить немного до мегабайта
  - - Муторно, придется прописывать каждую переменную. Данные сохранения 
    можно будет легко изменить даже не понимая в программировании почти 
    ничего.

Какой в играх используют? (это не обязательно 2 моих варианта могут быть и другие.)

Comment: Зависит от игры (например настольная, многопользовательская сетевая, и пр) и данных, которые нужно сохранять, цели сохранения, времени сохранения. Поэтому смотреть на варианты просто с позиции "это игра" - бессмысленно

Comment: А какая разница, json или не json? Хоть json, хоть bson, хоть yaml, хоть прости г-споди xml — важен не формат, а данные, которые запихали с использованием этого формата

Answer (score 4):

Первый вариант часто используют в симуляторах какой-нибудь приставки, типа NES, сохраняя дамп памяти игры.

Что касается второго варианта, то во-первых, легкость изменения будет зависеть от того, как всё это дело будет сохранятся. Понятное дело, что если в JSON, то любой кулхацкер разберется без проблем. Если же сохранять всё в бинарном виде, да еще и упаковывая, то будет несколько сложнее вычленять данные, да еще и софтину-редактор в последствии написать придется, чтобы не ковырять биты руками. А если еще зашифровать (а потом еще раз зашифровать :D)...

Во-вторых, не надо каждую переменную руками прописывать. Как правило, пишут адекватную сериализацию, чтобы самим всё делать просто и удобно. А объекты, большей частью, лежат, раскиданные по контейнерам, которые могут сохранить себя за счет того, что каждый объект, лежащий в них сам может себя сохранить, ну и затем восстановить, конечно же.